# Simplify Entity Framework Core query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I do not understand how to simplify this request

```
var dialogs = await dbContext.UsersDialogs
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
            .Select(x => new DialogModel
            {
                Id = x.DialogId,
                Login = x.Dialog.Name,
                Image = x.User.FacialImage,
                IsConfirm = x.Dialog.Messages.OrderBy(x => x.DateCreate).LastOrDefault().IsRead,
                DateTime = x.Dialog.Messages.OrderBy(x => x.DateCreate).LastOrDefault().DateCreate,
                LastMessage = x.Dialog.Messages.OrderBy(x => x.DateCreate).LastOrDefault().Content,
                LastUserId = x.Dialog.Messages.OrderBy(x => x.DateCreate).LastOrDefault().UserId
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

It will transform it into a request like this

```
SELECT [u].[DialogId] AS [Id], [d].[Name] AS [Login], [u0].[FacialImage] AS [Image], (
      SELECT TOP(1) [m].[IsRead]
      FROM [Messages] AS [m]
      WHERE [d].[Id] = [m].[DialogId]
      ORDER BY [m].[DateCreate] DESC) AS [IsConfirm], (
      SELECT TOP(1) [m0].[DateCreate] 
  FROM [Messages] AS [m0]
      WHERE [d].[Id] = [m0].[DialogId]
      ORDER BY [m0].[DateCreate] DESC) AS [DateTime], (
      SELECT TOP(1) [m1].[Content]
      FROM [Messages] AS [m1]
      WHERE [d].[Id] = [m1].[DialogId]
      ORDER BY [m1].[DateCreate] DESC) AS [LastMessage], (
      SELECT TOP(1) [m2].[UserId]
      FROM [Messages] AS [m2]
      WHERE [d].[Id] = [m2].[DialogId]
      ORDER BY [m2].[DateCreate] DESC) AS [LastUserId]
  FROM [UsersDialogs] AS [u]
  INNER JOIN [Dialogs] AS [d] ON [u].[DialogId] = [d].[Id]
  INNER JOIN [Users] AS [u0] ON [u].[UserId] = [u0].[Id]
  WHERE [u].[UserId] = @__userId_0
```

Сan I somehow optimize it? I don’t want to use a SQL query because Linq seems more convenient to me.

Comment: In the first select, you can create a anonymous object to store the `x.Dialog.Messages.OrderBy(x => x.DateCreate).LastOrDefault() and other direct property of x` and later in the select select create the object of `DialogModel`. That should generate the query better than your which has `Messages` table multiple times.

Comment: Providing you're on EF Core 5+, this looks like a good use case for [Filtered includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include)

Comment: TBH I like Svyatoslav's second alternative better than mine. Feel free to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created query which is translated directly to the same SQL. You can omit repeating queries by additional `Select`. Also `AsNoTracking` is not needed - EF Core do not tack custom entities.

```cs
var dialogs = await dbContext.UsersDialogs
    .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        UserDialog = x, 
        LastMessage = x.Dialog.Messages.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreate).FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .Select(x => new DialogModel
    {
        Id = x.UserDialog.DialogId,
        Login = x.UserDialog.Dialog.Name,
        Image = x.UserDialog.User.FacialImage,
        IsConfirm = x.LastMessage.IsRead,
        DateTime = x.LastMessage.DateCreate,
        LastMessage = x.LastMessage.Content,
        LastUserId = x.LastMessage.UserId
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

But quality of query above depends on quality of current EF Core LINQ translator. So, added another variant:

```cs
var query =  
    from ud in dbContext.UsersDialogs
    from lm in ud.Dialog.Messages.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreate)
       .Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new DialogModel
    {
        Id = ud.DialogId,
        Login = ud.Dialog.Name,
        Image = ud.User.FacialImage,
        IsConfirm = lm.IsRead,
        DateTime = lm.DateCreate,
        LastMessage = lm.Content,
        LastUserId = lm.UserId
    };

var dialogs = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This doesn't optimize the SQL query.

Comment: @GertArnold, it really depends on EF Core version and it's implementation. Added variant which should work in any case.

Comment: I tested it in EF core 6 & SQL Server. The alternative does a far better job.

Comment: Well in `linq2db` it will be optimised in all cases even in original message.

Comment: Yeah, linq2db, somehow many people keep using EF :)

Comment: Probably because it is Microsoft ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as the LINQ query is concerned, you can simplify it by using query syntax and `let`:

```cs
from d in dbContext.UsersDialogs
where d.UserId == userId
let lastMessage = d.Dialog.Messages.OrderBy(d => d.DateCreate).LastOrDefault()
select new DialogModel
{
    Id = d.DialogId,
    Login = d.Dialog.Name,
    Image = d.User.FacialImage,
    IsConfirm = lastMessage.IsRead,
    DateTime = lastMessage.DateCreate,
    LastMessage = lastMessage.Content,
    LastUserId = lastMessage.UserId
}
```

But that doesn't optimize the SQL query. EF generates the same subquery over and over again for each field from the Messages table. In SQL Server, the query plan doesn't optimize these subqueries away into one branch.

If you really want to optimize the SQL query you have to do something like this:

```cs
(
    from d in dbContext.UsersDialogs
    where d.UserId == userId
    select new
    {
        Id = d.DialogId,
        Login = d.Dialog.Name,
        Image = d.User.FacialImage,
        LastMessage = (from d.Dialog.Messages
                       orderby d.DateCreate
                       select new
                       {
                           IsConfirm = d.IsRead
                           d.DateCreate,
                           d.Content,
                           d.UserId
                       }).LastOrDefault()
    }
).AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => new DialogModel
{
    Id = x.DialogId,
    Login = x.Dialog.Name,
    Image = x.User.FacialImage,
    LastMessage.IsConfirm,
    LastMessage.DateCreate,
    LastMessage.Content,
    LastMessage.UserId
})
```

By adding `AsEnumerable`, which forces client-side evaluation of the last part of the query, EF generates a query with one subquery that uses the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` function to get the last message only once. But of course it's quite a hassle to do this. But it may be necessary if the first query suffer considerable performance hits.